# Repeating shmoneh esreh after forgetting an insertion

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

Why are you supposed to repeat shmoneh esreh on certain days if you forgot to say the special insertion pertaining to that day? If, for example, you realize at the end of shmoneh esre during aseret yemei tshuva that you forgot to say hamelech hakadosh, why does that warrant a repetition of the entire shmoneh esre?

Comment: What if you skipped a bracha? (I think you're trying to ask as opposed to something else. You should clarify that.)

Comment: I'm with @DoubleAA, the question is not clear.  Are you asking why by a hamelech hakadosh mistake we go back to the first bracha, or why if you mess up an addition and finish tefilla you go back to the beginning instead of to the mistake?

Comment: @YDK the latter. I just added the example because the site wouldn't let me post the question otherwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, as explained in Shulchan Aruch Horav Siman 114:8 if one changes the start and end of any Beracha from the way the Anshei Keneses Hagdolah established, then the Beracha is invalid hence the person did not fulfill his/her obligation. Now, the first 3 Berochos are considered one unit and the last 3 Berochos are considered one unit, therefore, if one made a mistake in one of them (meaning: 1 of the 3 first or 1 of the 3 last Berochos) then all 3 are invalid. However, the other 13 Berochos are separate units. In short, when one makes a mistake, and did not yet finish Shmone Esrei, s/he goes back to the beginning of that unit, i.e. if one forgets Tal Umatar they go back to the Borech Aleinu unit; if one forgets Hamelech Hakodosh they go back to the first 3 Berochos unit. But once s/he finished SA there is no way to go back to a unit without starting over from the beginning.
Besides the beginning and ending of Berochos there are certain phrases which the Anshei Keneses Hagdolah ordained that they must be said and if they were not said then that unit is invalid and one has to go back to that unit as explained above.
[Edit:] Besides the beginning and end of  Berochos there are other factors as well like the lack of mentioning the uniqueness of the day which is said of the recognition of the day given to us by HKBH, like Rosh Chodesh, calls for a repeat. The lack of mentioning Gevuras Geshamem is as important as Techiyas Hameisim (but it can't be mentioned in the winter because at that time of the year it's a curse) and therefore the lack thereof calls for a repeat. Asking for rain in Bareich Aleinu is very important because we are asking HKBH to keep us alive by giving us food (rain causes food to grow), lack of asking for our livelihood straight from The Source of Life calls for a repeat.(In the winter we don't ask for rain because then it's a curse.) By Hamelech Hakodosh (and also Hamelech Hamishpot according to those who apply the  same rules) it's because we must be aware and cognizant of the fact that HKBH is judging the world and lack of this recognition calls for a repeat.

Comment: Okay, but then why, for example, do we need to go back for saying משיב הרוח ומוריד הגשם in the wrong season, or the same with ותן טל ומטר, or missing Yaaleh Veyavo? None of these are the beginnings or ends of their respective berachos.

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer to include your concern

Comment: MeirZirkind, so basically your answer is that it is all arbitrary.

Comment: @DoubleAA Instead of "arbitrary", I prefer to say "fixed  by the Anshei Keneses Hagdolah". I have used the idea of approaching even a constitutional monarch  where there are rules of behaviour (see [here](http://abcnews.go.com/Politics/International/story?id=7228105&page=1#.T4bYn9miYoo)) to understand that there are rules when seeking audience with HaShem (lehavdil).

Comment: @DoubleAA: We always approach any teaching of the Chachamim as having a sound (non-arbitrary) basis, even if at the outset of the question, it appears inconsistent. To dispel the perception of arbitrariness, one needs to study each insertion separately, to understand the reason for why it does/does not require repeating the Shmonah Esrei.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok His answer does say that it's all arbitrary. If someone were to give an answer which explains why some things are important (and I'm sure such an answer exists), that would be wonderful and I would +1 it immediately.

Comment: Ping @SamGoldberg

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I added to my answer to try to address your concerns

Comment: @MeirZirkind, while your answer has much beneficial information, it doesn't really answer the question as it was brought out by Double AA and clarified by Ari A:  When I ended my tefilah after a crucial mistake, why must I go back to the beginning.  Why can't  just pick up from bracha where the mistake is?

Comment: When a person has a meeting/appointment with a king, while he's talking to the king and he forgets something he could return to that request but once he walks out he can't just run back in and say "I forgot to ask for..." he has to make a new appointment etc. The same thing, and all the more so, when praying to HKBH.  As example, when you make a cake batter and you forget sugar you could always put it in while your still making that batter, but once you bake it -try adding sugar then!

Comment: @DoubleAA: why don't you post as a separate question. I would like to try to answer, but I think it makes sense to flesh out the question and answer(s) more than is fitting for the comments section here.

Comment: @YDK: The tefila is defined by Chazal as a unit, made up of subunits (i.e. Avos, middle berachos, and final berachos), and at the most atomic level, each individual beracha. There are rules governing mistakes within the beracho, which requires going back to the beginning of that beracho. And there are rules which require to the beginning of the subunit (if you completed the subunit with a mistake). Once you complete the tefila it either has integrity as an entire unit or not. A mistake causes it to lose its integrity, and therefore the entire unit must be rebuilt (so to speak).