# Brachos l'vatala and repeating (all or part of) the Amidah

Tags: tefilla, blessing, shemoneh-esrei, derabanan

If saying a superfluous Amidah results in brachos l'vatala, as suggested [here](http://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.com/2012/04/q-page-3.html) ("However if one is davening after 1/2 hour after Chatzos he isn’t Yotzei and his Brachos are L’vatalah. See  Biur Halacha Siman 89 Dibur Hamaschil V’Achar"), then what of a [situation](http://ph.yhb.org.il/en/05-01-10/#_ze01fenref1_13) in which one must repeat all or part of the Amidah because of an omission? For what reason are those repeated brachas *not* l'vatala? (*Must* it be "because the rabbis said they weren't?")

Also, what about a tefilla nedava? Why are the brachas in that tefila not considered l'vatala?

Comment: When one must repeat the Amidah, the reason is that the first recitation was not valid and (by implication) those blessings were l'vatala. The second recitation is valid and so not l'vatala. The possibility of making a tefillas nedovo derives from the possibility to bring a korban nedovo (free-will sacrifice). So, if one were able to meet all the conditions for a valid  tefillas nedovo, the blessings would not be l'vatala.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Thanks. What are the conditions for something to be a valid tefilas nedovo? For example, must one have in mind that it is a nedovo?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @SAH see http://halachayomit.co.il/he/ReadHalacha.aspx?HalachaID=126

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok do the blessings in an amidah that ends up needing repeating only become l'vatala retroactively? if so, how exactly does that happen

Comment: ...Answer here maybe? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15688/1516

Comment: @SAH Good question. Could it be that the whole Amidah is assembled and "sent" as one unit after it is finished? If it is fatally flawed due to an omission then the blessings are levatala.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Interesting; I wonder if this is discussed in Chazal. (it must be!)

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Read something recently about how the first 4(?) brachos of shemona esrei are considered one unit/one bracha. Maybe there are other groups too. Could this be it?